# How do you know if an url is pointing to an endpoint in ASP.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I create a middleware

```
public class CustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (IsPage(context))
        {
            // Do something
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

I want IsPage(context) to response like this

- get test.com -> true
- get test.com/about -> true
- get test.com/product/1 -> true
- get test.com/main.js -> false
- get test.com/main.css -> false
- post test.com/search -> false

How do I do this?

Comment: Simply send a request to the endpoints and if the response is 200 return true otherwise false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you place your custom middleware after `UseRouting` in the middleware pipeline, you can use [`GetEndpoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpointhttpcontextextensions.getendpoint), which returns `null` if the request URL was not mapped to an endpoint:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (HttpMethods.IsGet(context.Request.Method)
        && context.GetEndpoint() != null)
    {
        // code
    }

    await next();
});
```